# How to store data in memory(RAM) using php without using Memcache/Redis or any other software?

Tags: php, performance

I want to implement a cache system in PHP consisting of following features

1) It should be able to store any(large or small) amount of data as long as the memory serves.(key value pair i.e. get & set)

2) It should have TTL

3) It should have LRU

4) Complexity should be O(1)

Constraints:
1) I am not allowed to use any middleware i.e. memcache or redis or any other in memory DB - so essentially implement memcache

**Now problem here is**

1. How can I interact with RAM using php?
2. PHP variables can be stored in memory but as soon as thread ends all variables are garbage collected. So you loose data?
3. May be use in memory mysql db engine? Can I?
4. Is it even possible to build such system using PHP?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)**

Comment: @gnat ok. So do you have any suggestions on the problem in hand?

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260) referred in prior comment?

Comment: @gnat Yes I did. And that is why I have laid down the problem to the point. Had it been a code related problem I would have posted it on stackoverflow instead. But because I wanted to hear out the suggestions I have come to programmers exchange. As far as scope of the problem is concerned it is very crystal clear to me and I have tried my best to provide those in my question. So it is neither an open ended question nor opinion based, answers ll be fairly 2 liners for each points. If any one needs any other info I am happy to provide.

Comment: scope of the problem is just what looks like a problem here. Five questions in one, with fifth being straight "What are my options?" - this looks way [too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490)

Comment: @gnat I agree with you on that. Edited it.

Comment: As soon as you want to store something in RAM with a longer lifetime than your current process, you either need to access the operating system directly, or use one of those middleware tools you mentioned. Accessing the OS directly from PHP and reimplement memcache that way in PHP is probably not what you really want, so either get the permission for using, for example, redis, or forget it.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609150/how-to-use-global-caching-in-php

Answer (score 4):

It's not a PHP specific problem. Whenever you want to share memory with multiple processes (PHP scripts terminate after they finish), use Shared Memory.
In PHP, [shm_attach()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-attach.php) should get you started.

Implementing cache on top of shm should be straight forward.

Comment: Yeah, this is better then tmpfs. I didn't know php had shm bindings.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of to get access to a chunk of  memory from php would be via tmpfs.

Then you write a hash table  implementation (+your cache logic) in terms of operations on file handles. This might be fun as an exercise but if you do this on someone else's dime you are not doing your job properly imo.